# What's wrong with my UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning SQL, and I'm trying to import data from one table to another. I've been having some success, but the update statement is giving me issues. I have a batting average column in the new table, and I'm trying to get the actual values into it.

> ie. hits (h) and at bats (ab) are in table 1 but I want h/ab = avg in table 2.

I tried:

```
UPDATE seasonbatting s 

Set OBP = (H/AB) 

FROM Batting b 

WHERE b.playerID = s.playerID 

AND b.yearID = s.yearID;
```

but I get an error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM batting b
>   WHERE s.playerID = b.playerID AND s.yearID = p.yearID' at line 3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support a `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE`. Your syntax looks more like Postgres or SQL Server.

You want:

```
UPDATE seasonbatting s JOIN
       Batting b
       ON b.playerID = s.playerID AND b.yearID = s.yearID
    Set s.OBP = (H/AB)
```